# android: checking for a configured action for intent.ACTION_SEND?

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm trying to launch the configured email client on android to send an attachment. Thing is, when I do it in the emulator, there is no email client configured to do any sending. I've also configured onActivityResult() to try and stop the train-wreck within the program but it doesn't seem to be getting control when things blow up. why?

this is my intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("text/plain");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{""});
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, CSV_MAIL_SUBJECT);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, CSV_MAIL_MSGBODY);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, createCSV.tempfile.toURI ());
try
{
   startActivityForResult (intent, CSV_MAIL_RESULT_CODE);
}
catch (ActivityNotFoundException anf)
{
   Log.d (TAG, "Activity not configured.");
   //TODO: toast or something here.. 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Thing is, when I do it in the emulator, there is no email client configured to do any sending

This should raise an `ActivityNotFoundException` from your `startActivityForResult()` call.

BTW, your MIME type is wrong. It should be `text/plain`.

> I've also configured onActivityResult() to try and stop the train-wreck within the program but it doesn't seem to be getting control when things blow up. why?

Because, if I'm right, `startActivityForResult()` is failing, so you will never be called with `onActivityResult()`.

Comment: Thanks! You were right on both counts. I added try/catch for ActivityNotFoundException and was able to gain control like I wanted. Furthermore, once I changed plain/text to text/plain, the mail application did indeed come up. Code changed above to reflect corrections.